# Uploading css files using s3cmd sync fails

Tags: html, css, amazon-s3, gruntjs, s3cmd

Trying to upload files to s3 bucket using this command

s3cmd -c sync -P -M dist/public/angular/styles/* s3://bucket/styles/

Getting this error

ERROR: Error parsing xml: not well-formed (invalid token): line 4, column 4
ERROR:

## 503 Service Unavailable

No server is available to handle this request.

HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

## 400 Bad request

Your browser sent an invalid request.

Answer (score 2):

`-c` is for specifying config file, not for command. So you should use:

```
s3cmd sync -P -M dist/public/angular/styles/* s3://bucket/styles/
```

It is possible the errors you are getting are due to `-M` option (guess MIME type)

Comment: My miss helloV its s3://bucket/styles/.  To add more details to the question. Im trying to upload a minified .css file